# How to draw a line using libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to draw some lines for debugging using libgdx but I failed. this is my code

```java
public class MainMenu extends Screen implements InputProcessor {

private OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch myBatch;
ShapeRenderer shapeDebugger;

public MainMenu(Game game) {
    super(game);
    camera= new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.update();}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    myBatch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(10);
    shapeDebugger.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeDebugger.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapeDebugger.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    shapeDebugger.line(2, 2, 5, 5);
    myBatch.end();
    }
}
```

I get an error from line

**shapeDebugger.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);**

@Pranav008

thank you very much. I didn't expect that I need to initiate it. but I've got a true problem. I draw the line to center of the game screen like this.

```
    Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(2);
    shapeDebugger.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeDebugger.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapeDebugger.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    shapeDebugger.line(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, 0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    shapeDebugger.end();
```

when I try to resize the screen it doesn't update the to center it goes far away to right.

Comment: What error did you get?  Is it run-time or compile-time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have got `nullpointerException` because you haven't made any object of ShapeRenderer.
Insert this line in your constructor.

```
shapeDebugger=new ShapeRenderer();
```

Comment: there is a problem I'm getting is to draw the line to center on resize

Comment: thats bcoz you have used Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight(). use your frustumwidth and frustumHeight instead and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 3):

Remember that nesting Shaperender with a SpriteBatch may cause problems.

Check this [link](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6860&p=31916&hilit=spritebatch+shaperenderer#p31916).

Comment: thank you, I just want this line for test as the main problem is my texture doesn't go to the center as expected

Answer (score 1):

My answer is mayby too late for you, but for people how have the same positioning problems.

Your second question about the position after a resize is because the viewport did not change. 
Aldo your window size changed your application stil is using the same pixel size set on create by the function `camera.setToOrtho`

Update the view port on a resize!

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void resize (int width, int height) {
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.update();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define  & initialize ShapeRenderer

```
ShapeRenderer shapeDebugger;

@Override
public void create() {
    shapeDebugger = new ShapeRenderer();
 ...
```

Draw line in render callback

```
    @Override
    public void render() {
        //render scene

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(69f / 255, 90f / 255, 100f / 255, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    ... 
   shapeDebugger.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeDebugger.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(10 / camera.zoom);
        shapeDebugger.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        shapeDebugger.line(screenWidth / 2, 0, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight);
        shapeDebugger.line(0, screenHeight / 2, screenWidth, screenHeight / 2);
        shapeDebugger.end();
```